# Method Order Between Parent and Inner UserControls

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms, page-lifecycle

I'm working on a project that has an outer `UserControl` called **Outer** that does some logic to determine which inner `UserControl` to load statically in its code. There are several inner controls, let's call them **Inner1**, **Inner2**, and **Inner3**.

ALL inner controls inherit the outer control, so:

> `Outer : System.Web.UI.UserControl`
>
> `Inner1 : Outer`
>
> `Inner2 : Outer`
>
> `Inner3 : Outer`

In `Outer.cs` I have some fields and methods that the inner controls access, e.g

```
List<string> foo = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    foo = MethodToPopulateFoo(); // this always works and returns a List<string> even if its empty
    // other stuff here
}
```

Now, here's my issue: if I call `DoStuff()` in the `Page_Load` of `Outer` I expect it runs, sets `foo` to a list and `foo` becomes no longer `null`. Then when the `Page_Load` of any of the inner controls runs, each of those can access `foo` and it will not be `null`.

This does not happen. Instead, in any `Page_Load` of `Inner1`, `Inner2`, or `Inner3` -- when I access `foo` it is always `null`. However, when the page loads in the browser, the `Page_Load` of `Outer` fully executes, then the `Page_Load` of `InnerX` loads, so I'm perplexed as to why `foo` is `null` again when I call the inner control's `Page_Load` which I know runs after the outer control (which sets `foo`).

If I were to remove the `DoStuff()` call from the outer `Page_Load` and move into into each individual inner `Page_Load`, it works fine. I would like to avoid this though.

Comment: FYI, there's nothing special about User Controls in terms of life cycle or method order. They are the same as all other kind of control.

Answer (score 0):

The Page_Load method of the inner controls is called before Page_Load of the outer control. But you still have a couple of options:

You could either use Lazy initialization, e.g.

```
List<string> _foo;
List<string> Foo
{
   get 
   {
      if (_foo == null)
         _foo = new List<string>();
      return _foo;
   }
}
```

or you initialize foo in your outer control (every class should initialize it's own objects) and access it not from Page_Load, but from Page_PreRender in your inner controls. You could also create the List in Page_Init or Page_PreLoad.